# Repeating function n times until condition is met

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements

I have a problem regarding checking and repeating a function based on output from program for analyzing a process. I have a program that saves log files in text format. Now my script checks that log for keywords such as: `'Error'`, `'Warning'`, or `'Executed'`.

There are three possible combinations of those keywords:

- case 1): Only error or warning,
- case 2): Executed, but error or warning is present,
- case 3): Executed without errors.

When case 1 or 2 happens I want to use program one more time in hopes that this time it will work correctly. But I just want to do so let's say 3 times, and if after that errors will still occur I want to close program and reset the power of the device I'm analyzing. I have a bunch of functions written and I don't know how to repeat one of them based on the input from another one.

Here is my code:

```
def execute_program():
    Log.step('Run flashing script')
    run_command('GOTO load_application')
    wait(seconds=50)
    run_command(r'AREA.SAVE C:\Users\Log_1.txt')
    return 0

def check_log():
    path_log_1 = open(r"C:\Users\Log_1.txt", "r+")
    content_of_log_1 = path_log_1.read()
    if message_5 in content_of_log_1:
       print(r'Executed present in file')
       return True
    return False


def check_log_error_message_1():
    path_log_1 = open(r"C:\Users\Log_1.txt", "r+")
    content_of_log_1 = path_log_1.read()
    if message_1 in content_of_log_1:
        print(r'Error present in file')
        return True
    return False

def check_log_error_message_2():
    path_log_1 = open(r"C:\Users\Log_1.txt", "r+")
    content_of_log_1 = path_log_1.read()
    if message_2 in content_of_log_1:
        print(r'Warning present in file')
        return True
    return False

def check():
    check_log()
    print(r'Value of function check_log ', check_log())
    check_log_error_message_1()
    print(r'Value of function check_log_error_message_1',
    check_log_error_message_1())
    check_log_error_message_2()
    print(r'Value of function check_log_error_message_2 ',
    check_log_error_message_2())

#Checking which conditions are True and False

    if check_log() is True:
        print(r'Program executed')
        var_1 = 1
        print(r"Value of var_1 = ", var_1)
    else:
        print(r'Program not executed')
        var_1 = 0
        print(r"Value of var_1 = ", var_1)


    if check_log_error_message_1() or check_log_error_message_2() is True:
        print(r'Warning or error found')
        var_error_1 = 1
        print("Value of var_error_1 = ", var_error_1)
    else:
        print(r'No warnings or errors found')
        var_error_1 = 0
        print(r"Value of var_error_1 = ", var_error_1)

    if var_error_1 == var_1:
        print(r"Error occurred")
        restart_program()
    elif var_error_1 > var_1:
        print(r'Error occurred')
        restart_program()
    elif var_error_1 < var_1:
        print(r'Program executed, saving log')
        close()

def restart_program():
    print(r'Attempting to restart the device')
    nrun_script(script_path="",)
    wait(seconds=20)
    run_command('GOTO load_application')
    wait(seconds=50)
    run_command(r'AREA.SAVE C:\Users\Log_1.txt', core_no=2)
    check()

execute_program()
check()
```

And now all I want is that to try in case of recurring errors 3 times or until there is no errors in my log file. I tried to do it with variable I and incrementation with `while` loop, but can't quite implement it into my code.

Comment: Get out of the habit of writing `if xxx is True:`. Just write `if xxx:`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my first version I didn't use that, but kinda decided to when I was tinkering with my code while trying to fix my problem.

Comment: You're not consistent about it. You left out the first `is True` in `if check_log_error_message_1() or check_log_error_message_2() is True:`

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. The bodies of `check` and `restart_program` aren't indented.

Comment: Yes, sry about indentation, some parts didn't paste right. So it should be if check_log_error_message_1() is True or check_log_error_message_2() is True?
Will there be a difference if I would delete is True? -> check_log_error_message_1()  or check_log_error_message_2() ?

Comment: You could implement this as a [Finite State Machine (FSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that could be in a state corresponding to each of the 3 possible cases, plus an initial one and final one, along with a count of attempts. You could then iteratively execute the function, check the results and then transition to a different state based on them *and the value of counter*.